# How to display markers on google map using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps

I need to display markers from database using PHP codeigniter
I will not get map

```
function initialize() {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(18.5236, 73.8478);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    // Add 5 markers to the map at random locations.
    var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(18.5236,73.8478);
    var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(19.5236,75.8478);

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(southWest,northEast);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
    var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();


//If I comment below line it show blank map

    beaches =  [ <?php foreach($records as $row) echo "[".$row->property_title.', '.$row->property_latitude.', '.$row->property_longitude.'],'?>]"

    for (var i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
          var beach = beaches[i];
          var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatLng,
              map: map,
              title: beach[0]            
          });           
      }                                           
}
```

Comment: check for extra commas, quotes or parenthesis

Comment: I believe the `"` at the end of your  `beaches =  [ <?php foreach($...` line should be a `;`

Comment: If its of any use, I have a CI Google maps library that might help. If you're interested you can find it here: http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$row->property_title` is a string, it needs to between quotes:

```
echo "['".$row->property_title."', ".$row->property_latitude.', '.$row->property_longitude.'],'?>]"
```

Alternatively, you could use `json_encode` to output your array:

```
<?php
$beaches = array();
foreach ($records as $row) {$beaches[] = array($row->property_title, $row->property_latitude, $row->property_longitude);}
echo 'beaches = ' . json_encode($beaches) . ';';
?>
```

Comment: `json_encode()` should produce exact the wanted result. If you do your SQL query right (assuming `$records` contains an SQL result) you can even drop the foreach loop and use `json_encode($records)`.

Comment: I have image path also as last parameter it encode it "uploads\/default_poster_thumb.JPG"

Comment: To disable escaping slashes: if you're using PHP > 5.4.0, use `json_encode($beaches,  JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)`. Otherwise, use `str_replace('\/', '/', json_encode($beaches));`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $beaches = "['".$row->property_title."', '".$row->property_latitude."', '".$row->property_longitude."']";

var beaches=[<?php echo $beaches;?>];
```